# Javascript: JScript file parsed as text on Apache server and can't be run

Tags: javascript, apache, cpanel

I was working for a client, and his server doesn't allow running javascript. I tried to re-create and re-upload the JS files but the server keeps changing the file type into text. What's up with this? See screenshot below...

[image: Cpanel File Manager]

Comment: have you found any solution for this? i am facing a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .js file MIME type in your Apache http.conf with AddType:

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

This will tell Apache to serve `.js` files with the application/javascript type you need.

Comment: Can this be done inside Cpanel X? I tried to add it via "Apache Handlers" and "MIME Types" option under "Advanced" setting but no go.