# Included Javascript Shows Javascript Code Instead Of Output

Tags: javascript

I am using caledar.js file by adding it to html code.

Till server migration, it was working perfectly. But now Instead of showing calendar, calendar.js code is shown...

My code to add calendar.js is as follows :

```
 <div id="Calendar" src="calendar.php"> </div>
 <div id="Events" src="events.php"> </div>
 <script language="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
```

Now instead of showing calendar, calendar.js code is shown on webpage as follows (eg):

```
var bustcachevar=1; //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
var bustcacheparameter="";

function createRequestObject(){
try {
    xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   catch(e)    {
    alert('Sorry, but your browser doesn\'t support XMLHttpRequest.');
};
return xmlhttp;
};

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
var page_request = createRequestObject();

if (bustcachevar) bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
page_request.send(null)

page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    loadpage(page_request, containerid)
}

}
function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)) {
            document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
};
}


function LoadMonth(month, year) {
ajaxpage("calendar.php?month="+month+"&year="+year, "Calendar")
 }

function LoadEvents(date) {
ajaxpage("events.php?date="+date, "Events")
 }

LoadMonth();
```

I also tried adding following code in css file

```
script{
 display:none;
}
head{
 display:none;
}
```

Is there any need to change in above calendar.js code as server is migrated from **php5.3 to php5.4** ?

Comment: That `.....` might actually be important. How do you actually start the calendar creation?

Comment: Open up developer tools, look at the network tab on load, and see what mime type the js is being served up as. My guess you are missing a file type handling on your server (apache) and it's serving it up as `text/plain` or something similar.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100557/javascript-jscript-file-parsed-as-text-on-apache-server-and-cant-be-run for an example

Comment: What do you mean by "calendar.js code is shown"? Is the JavaScript code displayed on the webpage?

Comment: @DaveNewton Calendar is created through calendar.php .....

Comment: @scrappledcola - The MIME type for my file is: application/x-javascript.....

Comment: @samsonthehero yes, code in calendar.js is shown on webpage

Comment: Do you see anything else on the network tab? Is the script being executed at all (if you set a breakpoint for example, does it stop). What is being returned in the AJAX response? Could it be the calendar.js code again because of a bug in how the url is passed?

Comment: @samsonthehero is it possible that error is due to upgradation of server from php 5.3 to php 5.4 and if yes what can be solution ?

Comment: How are you implementing the `src` attribute on the `div`s? The content type might be a problem. It really should be "text/javascript".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I Got Solution. I am posting it as an answer so others may get answer if they are facing same issue...

I added following code in my root `.htaccess` file and now it works....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```